# Convert Date into another format with time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert a date string "2017-03-25 19:10:00 +0000" in the "2017-03-25 07:10 PM".

But No any luck.Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a this?

Comment: Yeah tried, But give wrong result.

Comment: what result it gives?

Comment: Dude, Sorry the falut was my side. I used yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a. I have used yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a.It gives me right result. 
Thanks a lot. It saved my lots of time.

Comment: you are welcome brother.

Comment: You need an **input** date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` to convert string to date and an **output** date format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a` to convert the date to string.

Comment: You should post the code for the solution that you found as an answer to your own question and then accept it. That way you can help others.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *dateString = @"2017-03-25 19:10:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSString *result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```